# Show: $\int f\, d\mu=\sum\limits_{y\in f(X)}y\cdot\mu(f^{-1}(y)))$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

> > Let $f\colon X\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}_{\geq 0}$ be a measurable function which only takes a countable number of values. Show that
> >     $$
> > \int f\, d\mu=\sum\limits_{y\in f(X)}y\cdot\mu\left(f^{-1}(y)\right).
> > $$

Here is my idea resp. proof:

Consider $(X,\mathfrak{U},\mu)$ and $f$ as mentioned above. I call the values of $f$ as $y_1,y_2,y_3,...$ (resp. finite values). Now set
$$
X_{y_i}:=f^{-1}(\left\{y_i\right\}).
$$
Then $X$ is the disjunct union of these sets, i.e.
$$
X=\bigcup\limits_{y_i\in f(X)}X_{y_i}, X_{y_i}\cap X_{y_j}=\emptyset~\forall~i\neq j.
$$
Because for the Lebesgue integral it is$\int\limits_{A\cup B}f(x)\, d\mu=\int\limits_A f(x)\, d\mu+\int\limits_B f(x)\, d\mu$ for disjunct sets $A,B\in\mathfrak{U}$, it is
$$
\int_X f(x)\, d\mu=\sum\limits_{y_i\in f(X)}\int\limits_{X_{y_i}}f(x)\, d\mu=\sum\limits_{y_i\in f(X)}\int_X\chi_{X_{y_i}}(x)f(x)\, d\mu
$$
The functions
$$
\chi_{X_{y_i}}(x)f(x)=\begin{cases}y_i, & x\in X_{y_i}\\0, &\mbox{ elsewhere}\end{cases}
$$
are simple functions and for those functions the Lebesgue integral is defined as
$$
\int\limits_X\chi_{X_{y_i}}(x)f(x)\, d\mu=y_i\cdot \mu\left(f^{-1}(\left\{y_i\right\})\right).
$$
So it is
$$
\sum\limits_{y_i\in f(X)}\int_X\chi_{X_{y_i}}(x)f(x)\, d\mu=\sum\limits_{y_i\in f(X)}y_i\cdot\mu\left(f^{-1}(\left\{y_i\right\})\right)
$$

Finished!

I would like to know if my proof is correct.

With regards!

Comment: Looks fine to me. +1 for a good post.